# Nested module and package imports in Python

Tags: python, python-import

We have a VERY large python project (200+ files)

and up till now I've been handling it dependencies very well there are  a few spots where some new part of the project used and existing part from another module and it's been simple enough to make sure everything imports in the right order.

but now I'm getting into trouble when a module in a sub-package requires a module form another sub-package

to illustrate take this simplified version

the file system

```
Core
|__init__.py
|Database
-|__init__.py
-|Dialogs
--|__init__.py
--|SomeDialog.py
-|Controls
--|__init__.py
--|SomeControl.py
|Frame.py
```

now if in `SomeControl.py` I import `SomeDialog.py` via this statement 
`from Core.Dialogs.SomeDialog import SomeDialog`
where `SomeDialog` is a class in the file `Somedialog`

When I go to `import Core` in the main application I get an error that "Core" has no module "Database"

how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide some small test case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: `import Core` has error? is there `__init__.py` the same `level` to Core?

Answer (score 0):

This case names "circular imports". You can import your modules in functions and methods just you need to use them.

```
# SomeDialog.py
class Dialog(object):
    def draw(self):
        from ..Controls.SomeControl import control
        control()

# SomeControl.py
def control():
    from ..Dialogs.SomeDialog import all_dialogs
    do_something(all_dialogs)
```

Comment: is there really no other way? as I said this is a HUGE code base and having to do this every where necessary would be well... exhaustive. and the imports arnt circular, only SomeControl.py requires SomeDialog.py not the other way around

Comment: In theory, you can write function that will do lazy imports. Instead of writing `import somedialog` in the beginning of file, you'll write something like `somedialog = lazy_import("somedialog")` that will internally import module only when you try to get attribute of `somedialog`. But this solution looks ugly.

Comment: No, i had never use such solutions. For example i've googled http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/demandimport.py